# WebSphere IHS / Liberty Intelligent Management / ODR Problems

Tags: routes, websphere-liberty, ibmhttpserver

We are currently using Intelligent Management / ODR in our WebSphere IHS / Plugin 8.5.5.11 and Liberty Profile 16.0.0.4 environments. I am upgrading to Liberty 17.0.0.4 and IHS / Plugins 9.0.0.6. The upgrade to WLP went smoothly. However, when I've upgraded the IHS / Plugins to 9.0.0.6, I cannot get Intelligent Management / ODR to work for me. I basically copied the Plugin key files from the older environment. I generated a new `plugin-cfg.xml` file in 9.0.0.6, but then replaced the section of the config file dealing with clusters with the old section for Intelligent Management from the 8.5.5.11 config file. I'm wondering if I missed something in the IHS config that I also need to do.

Here is the error message I am getting in the `http_plugin.log` (the documentation for this error basically just says "fix your config", without giving any details):

```
ERROR: lib_odr: initializeODR: Failed to initialize ODR environment
```

Here is the Intelligent Management section from my `plugin-cfg.xml`:

```
<Property Name="Keyfile" Value="/opt/IBM/WebSphere/Plugins/config/w3svcs-webserver1/plugin-key.kdb"/>
<Property Name="Stashfile" Value="/opt/IBM/WebSphere/Plugins/config/w3svcs-webserver1/plugin-key.sth"/>
<IntelligentManagement>
    <Property name="webserverName" value="w3svcs-webserver1"/>
    <ConnectorCluster enabled="true" maxRetries="-1" name="default" retryInterval="60">
       <Property name="uri" value="/ibm/api/dynamicRouting"/>
       <Connector host="stgpccggww3n01.w3-969.ibm.com" port="19440" protocol="https">
          <Property name="keyring" value="/opt/IBM/WebSphere/Plugin/config/w3svcs-webserver1/plugin-key.kdb"/>
       </Connector>
    </ConnectorCluster>
 </IntelligentManagement>
```

Do I need any configuration updates to my IHS `httpd.conf` file? Or some other config I may be missing?

Comment: Nothing in httpd.conf should be needed. This error should be the dlopen/dlsym of the libodr.so.  Are you sure no message precedes that initializeODR msg?

Answer (score 0):

You should increase the plugin loglevel to Trace to provide more details before the load failure is reported. Did you replace any files other than the plugin key/sth files ?